# Can the value and setter from useState go into separate contexts?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Given something like the following:

```
const ctx = createContext([])
const TopLevelComponent = () => {
    const [val, setVal] = useState(0)
    return (
        <ctx.Provider value={[val, setVal]}>
            // actually components go here
        </ctx.Provider>
    )
}
```

it occurs to me that any child component that uses this `ctx` gets both the setter and value, but if that child component *only* sets a value, it doesn't actually need to re-render when the value changes. Given that, I thought it might be reasonable to break it out into 2 contexts - one for the getter, one for the setter, like:

```
const valueCtx = createContext(0)
const setterCtx = createContext(undefined)

const TopLevelComponent = () => {
    const [val, setVal] = useState(ctx)
    return (
        <valueCtx.Provider value={val}>
            <setterCtx.Provider value={setVal}>
                // actually components go here
            </setterCtx.Provider>
        </valueCtx.Provider>
    )
}
```

So my question is, fundamentally, is my understanding of how react rerenders accurate? Is there any issue with doing this?

Secondly, if this is a reasonable approach, *how* does react know to rerender components that rely on `valueCtx` after a call to the setter contained in `setterCtx`?

Comment: This will easily explode the number of contexts you'll be using for little/no advantage. You're trying to prevent re-rendering a component that only needs the setter when the value changes, but how likely is that "setter" component going to be expensive? Probably very unlikely.

Comment: Child components will rerender anyway when you change the value of the context. Splitting the context will do nothing. Rerendering is ok.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Ah I see - I wrote a demo to verify, looks like you're correct. Thanks :) https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-oskar-ek2515?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The state updater function is guaranteed to be a stable reference, the the state value is what is variable, and as pointed out, will trigger a rerender of children components anyway. Just let React do its thing until you've an *actual* detectable and measurable performance issue to start using memoization tools and other patterns to reduce unnecessary expensive renders.

Comment: @DrewReese This question is about understanding the framework more than eeking out an extra ms of performance. Personally, I think understanding the tools you use is important.

Comment: No worries. Understanding that React is optimized pretty well out-of-the-box is IMO important too. All too often I see devs trying to memoize and eliminate as many rerenders as possible and then they wonder why large chunks of their app aren't updating as they expect. Premature optimizations should be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. I took the code sandbox you created (that is in the comment) and changed some parts of the code. You will see that when I change the `val` with the setter, only the component that uses `valueCtx` context gets re-rendered.

Here is the link to the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-babbage-d4enwu?file=/src/App.js:91-99